# How to add mean as a point in bwplot in R?

Tags: r

Apologies for the simple questions I have posted, but I am new to R and I'm finding it rather difficult to find solutions via the documentation avaliable.

**I would simply like to add a mean as a point to the box and whisker plots using bwplot. I have seen similar questions but they usually used ggplot2 or another package.**

I have had some help with constructing a rectangle range with a panel function to add to the plot, so I suspected that my current problem could be solved with further additions to my panel function.

I have attempted to use `panel.average` to add to my panel function, but have had no luck. Using the example code below, As an example below, I have tried:

```
library(lattice)
library(MASS)
data <- Cars93[,c("Manufacturer", "Price")] 

testpanel <- function (x,y,...) {
  panel.rect(xleft = 0, xright = 5, ybottom = 15, ytop = 25, col="aliceblue", border = 0)
  panel.average(x,y, fun=mean, identifier="point") #my attempt to add a point to represent the mean
  panel.bwplot(x, y, ...)
}

bwplot(Price ~ Manufacturer, 
       data=rbind(transform(data, Manufacturer="All"), data[data$Manufacturer=="Chevrolet",]),
       panel = testpanel,
       pch='|'

       )
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

- As a side note - if someone could direct me to any good tutorials or resources to work with panels in lattice and graphing in general in R - it would be greatly appreciated. I am finding the R documentation quite difficult to decipher.

Comment: I think most people who tackled lattice "bought the book". There's a website: http://lmdvr.r-forge.r-project.org/figures/figures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the author of `bwplot`, Deepayan Sarkar, answered it 9 years ago on Rhelp:

```
panel.mean <- function(x, y, ...) {
    tmp <- tapply(x, y, FUN = mean)
    panel.points(tmp, seq(tmp), pch = 20, ...)
}
```

I needed to switch the x and y values to get it to work:

```
panel.mean <- function(x, y, ...) {
    tmp <- tapply(y, x, FUN = mean); print(tmp)
    panel.points(y=tmp, x=seq_along(tmp), ...)
}

bwplot(Price ~ Manufacturer, 
       data=rbind(transform(data, Manufacturer="All"), data[data$Manufacturer=="Chevrolet",]),
       panel = function(x,y, ...) { panel.bwplot(x,y,...)
                 panel.mean(x,y, pch='*', col="red", cex=3)
                            }
       )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that is great. On my real dataset however, for the 'All' group, I have some NAs in the dataset, is there a way to modify the panel.mean function to remove the NAs? I have tried adding na.rm = TRUE, but to no luck...Thanks again.